# JAX-RS method not return JSON data from object

Tags: json, angularjs, jax-rs

Hi I have simple Angular and JAX RS application. My class:

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

File AngularCtrl.js is Angular controller:

```
    (function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    var serviceURI = "/Airlines/rest/";
    app.controller('flightCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.value;
            getAllUsers($scope, $http);
        }]);
    function getAllUsers($scope, $http) {
        $http.get(serviceURI + "flights").success(function (data) {
            $scope.value = data;
        }).error(function (error) {
            alert("Some Error Occurred!");
        });
    }

})();
```

Rest class:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/flights")
public class FlightRest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User listAll() {
        User user = new User("John", "Thompson");
        System.out.println("Before return");
        return user;
    }

}
```

and simple view:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Arilines</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-app="app">
        <div  data-ng-controller="flightCtrl">
            {{value.firstName}} {{value.lastName}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/AngularCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I start my application i alwas get a alert:

> alert("Some Error Occurred!");

What's wrong in my class and not success only error? Why not get a JSON data? I'm sure that my request arrives to JAX-RS class because in console i see below message from class

> System.out.println("Before return");

Comment: The message "Some Error Occurred!" is not very clear. Try using the developer tools to check the HTTP error. Can be `401`, `403`, `404`, `500`...

Comment: My guess is you're missing a JSON provider. Do you have one?

Answer (score 0):

Your JAX-RS class has no issues. It returns a json as expected. I executed the code and it display the user name correctly on the browser.

The only tweak I had to do was to add headers to my response from JAX-RS to allow cross domain access(CORS), since I hosted the REST service on another port.
Here is the tweak I did :-

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listAll() {
    User user = new User("John", "Thompson");
    System.out.println("Before return");
    return Response.status(Status.OK)
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
    .entity(user)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```